# Survival probability given an average life expectancy

Tags: statistics, probability

How can I obtain the probability that one person will die at or before a certain age if I only have the average of the life expectancy?

For instance, a person is 45 years old. The life expectancy is 60 years. Can I find the probability the person will die at age 45 (not before 44, but not after 45)?

Comment: Not without an assumption about the underlying distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the comments above and after some searching, I found these datasets 
([WHO Life tables by country](http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.60000?lang=en))
which helped me with the prediction that I want. In fact, apparently is imposible to determine the probability of survival with just the life expectancy, these datasets provide the survival probability for  age based on the gender and the country.

Comment: Although it's true that in general you need to have the whole survival distribution, you can probably get an approximation by assuming a survival distribution which has just a few parameters. E.g. I suspect that the survival curves for different countries have pretty much the same shape, and a scaling factor (to account for different life span) accounts for much of the difference.